# Applying a schema to a Spark's Dataset of a java object

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

There's a similar issue here: [How to add a schema to a Dataset in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965161/how-to-add-a-schema-to-a-dataset-in-spark)

However the issue I'm facing is that I have an already predefined `Dataset<Obj1>` and I want to define a schema to match its data-members. The end goal is to be able to join between two java objects.

Sample code:

```
Dataset<Row> rowDataset = spark.getSpark().sqlContext().createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema).toDF();
Dataset<MyObj> objResult = rowDataset.map((MapFunction<Row, MyObj>) row ->
        new MyObj(
                row.getInt(row.fieldIndex("field1")),
                row.isNullAt(row.fieldIndex("field2")) ? "" : row.getString(row.fieldIndex("field2")),
                row.isNullAt(row.fieldIndex("field3")) ? "" : row.getString(row.fieldIndex("field3")),
                row.isNullAt(row.fieldIndex("field4")) ? "" : row.getString(row.fieldIndex("field4"))
        ), Encoders.javaSerialization(MyObj.class));
```

If I'm printing the schema of the row dataset I get the schema as expected:

```
rowDataset.printSchema();

root
 |-- field1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- field2: string (nullable = false)
 |-- field3: string (nullable = false)
 |-- field4: string (nullable = false)
```

If I'm printing the Object dataset I'm losing the actual schema

```
objResult.printSchema();

root
 |-- value: binary (nullable = true)
```

The question is how can I apply a schema for the `Dataset<MyObj>`?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: probably code snippet about your problem would help us to recommend something.

Comment: @squid, I provided a code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the code snippet, I tried and spark behaves as expected, it seems the rootcause of your problem is something else not the map function.

```
 SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate();
        Dataset<Row> ds = session.read().text("<some path>");
        Encoder<Employee> employeeEncode = Encoders.bean(Employee.class);
        ds.map(new MapFunction<Row, Employee>() {
            @Override
            public Employee call(Row value) throws Exception {
                return new Employee(value.getString(0).split(","));
            }
        }, employeeEncode).printSchema();
```

**Output:**

```
root
 |-- age: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

**//Employee Bean**

```
public class Employee {
    public String name;
    public Integer age;
    public Employee(){

    }
    public Employee(String [] args){
        this.name=args[0];
        this.age=Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I wasn't familiar with bean Encoder. Only during this issue investigation I got to know it. This is the closest answer I was able to got although it's not perfect since it doesn't support *yet* all data types: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Encoders.html#bean(java.lang.Class)